# How do I add a Div button below the author name on posts?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, button

I have the HTML for the button. But I want to put it in the bottom of every post header. I found the area in my functions that deals with my header, but obviously there is a special way to put the button code in the functions, which I cant figure it out. I hope you can help me, below is all the information:

---> My button code :

```
<div class="cb-tip-button" data-content-location="" data-href="//www.coinbase.com/tip_buttons/show_tip" data-to-user-id="52958dae01e73713d400002d"></div>
<script>!function(d,s,id) {var js,cjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],e=d.getElementById(id);if(e){return;}js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="https://www.coinbase.com/assets/tips.js";cjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,cjs);}(document, 'script', 'coinbase-tips');</script>
```

----> This is my theme functions for that area. I high-lighted the part I think it has to due with:
http://pastebin.com/XyB9yx1m

-----> Attached is a picture of how I want the button to look.

[My image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYbrV.png)

Comment: `?>ADD CODE HERE</header><!-- .entry-header -->` Just place it after closing php tag and before closing header tag. You will probably need to add some css to get padding and alignment right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
<header class="entry-header">
    <?php if (
        fearless_get_option( 'singular_featured_image_enabled' )
            && 'audio' != $format
            && 'gallery' != $format
            && 'video' != $format
        ) {
            fearless_post_thumbnail();
        }
    ?>

    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php single_post_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php
    printf(
        apply_atomic_shortcode(
            'entry_byline',
            '<div class="entry-byline">' . __( 'By [entry-author]   [entry-published]  ', 'fearless' ) . '</div>'
        ),
        sprintf(
            _n(
                '1 View',
                '%1$s Views',
                get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Views', true ),
                'fearless'
            ),
            get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Views', true )
        )
    );
    ?>
<div class="cb-tip-button" data-content-location="" data-href="//www.coinbase.com/tip_buttons/show_tip" data-to-user-id="52958dae01e73713d400002d"></div>
<script>!function(d,s,id) {var js,cjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],e=d.getElementById(id);if(e){return;}js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="https://www.coinbase.com/assets/tips.js";cjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,cjs);}(document, 'script', 'coinbase-tips');</script>
</header><!-- .entry-header -->
```

Should now be added into the header.

It just needed to be above the end `</header>` tag.